# How I can view and block specific applications temporarily from accessing Internet?

Tags: security, internet

I don't want to block any application permanently from accessing internet. I just want to block some specific applications for a particular time period to gain speed in running some other.

I know about one such great tool - that is "Comodo firewall". It can smoothly block and accurately display apps accessing internet. The only problem of installing this is, Windows recommends only one firewall apps and as Im running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate there will be complications if I install this one.

I need a tool which can accurately display which apps are accessing internet (through which port) and how much data they are receiving or sending. I also need some arrangement within the app so that I can easily temporarily block that app from accessing internet.

Comment: Can't you can just disable the Windows firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always disable your firewall and use the one that comes with your AV or an external one (like the one you pointed out).

Another option is to use [NetLimiter Monitor](http://www.netlimiter.com/) and configure settings in windows firewall.

Either way you will achieve what you want. Keep in mind that NetLimiter Monitor gives quite detailed stats, so you might want to give this a try.

Comment: Mtashev: NetLimiter Pro is the correct app which meets my needs. Thanks for the answer.